# Jenkins Warnings Next Generation plugin: Java compiler warnings are ignored - why?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to get my warnings using the Warnings Next Generation plugin. While it works fine for PMD, Checkstyle, Maven etc. I can't get it to work for the Java compiler.

Specifically, I have warnings coming from the Java compiler itself, like

```
08:52:34.395 [WARNING] /my/path/to/workspace/src/main/java/my/package/TemporalJsonSeqFiling.java:[86,76] redundant cast to long
```

and also warnings issued by the Checker Framework, like

```
10:16:33.787 [WARNING] /my/path/to/workspace/src/main/java/my/package/CollatorOrdering.java:[107,46] [override.param.invalid] Incompatible parameter type for s.
  Method
    @Initialized @NonNull CollationKey apply(@Initialized @NonNull <anonymous my.package.CollatorOrdering$2> this, @Initialized @NonNull String p0) in <anonymous my.package.CollatorOrdering$2>
  cannot override
    @Initialized @Nullable CollationKey apply(@Initialized @NonNull Function<@Initialized @NonNull String, @Initialized @NonNull CollationKey> this, @Initialized @Nullable String p0) in com.google.common.base.Function
  found   : @Initialized @NonNull String
  required: @Initialized @Nullable String
```

Both are ignored. I'm still using JDK 8 - is this the problem?

(I looked at the source in https://github.com/jenkinsci/analysis-model/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/hm/hafner/analysis/parser/JavacParser.java - and the regular expression looks pretty complex  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: We use timestamps in our Maven log, and the regular expression for the Java compiler parser can't cope with that.

I filed an issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56737